# Can anonymous class be used as return types in C++?

Tags: c++, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

Is there any way to use anonymous classes in C++ as return types?

I googled that this may work:

```
struct Test {} * fun()
{
}
```

But this piece of code doesn't compile, the error message is:

> new types may not be defined in a return type

Actually the code doesn't make any sense, I just want to figure out whether an anonymous class can be used as return type in C++.

Here is my code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int mx = [] () -> struct { int x, y ; } { return { 99, 101 } ; } ().x ;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with g++ xx.cpp -std=c++0x, the compiler compains:

```
expected primary-expression before '[' token.
```

Comment: *new types may not be defined in a return type* - Seems like the compiler already answered your question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice: These code snippets no longer work in the latest versions of g++. I compiled them with version 4.5.2, but versions 4.6.1 and 4.7.0 no longer accept them.

---

You *can* declare an anonymous struct as the return type of a lambda function in C++11. But it's not pretty. This code assigns the value 99 to `mx`:

```
int mx = [] () -> struct { int x, y ; } { return { 99, 101 } ; } ().x ;
```

The ideone output is here: http://ideone.com/2rbfM

In response to cheng's request:

The lambda function is a new feature in C++11. It's basically an anonymous function. Here is a simpler example of a lambda function, that takes no arguments and returns an `int`:

```
[] () -> int { return 99 ; }
```

You can assign this to a variable (you have to use `auto` to do this):

```
auto f = [] () -> int { return 99 ; } ;
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
int mx = f() ;
```

Or you can call it directly (which is what my code does):

```
int mx = [] () -> int { return 99 ; } () ;
```

My code just uses `struct { int x, y ; }` in place of `int`. The `.x` at the end is the normal `struct` member syntax applied to the function's return value.

This feature is not as useless as it might appear. You can call the function more than once, to access different members:

```
auto f = [] () -> struct {int x, y ; } { return { 99, 101 } ; } ;
cout << f().x << endl ;
cout << f().y << endl ;
```

You don't even have to call the function twice. This code does exactly what the OP asked for:

```
auto f = [] () -> struct {int x, y ; } { return { 99, 101 } ; } () ;
cout << f.x << endl ;
cout << f.y << endl ;
```

Comment: [] () -> int { return 99 ; }   What is the meaning of [] () -> before the labmda function?

Comment: I find it interesting that this is allowed, but with a normal function using a late return type it is not.  I would have expected the grammar to be similar in those two cases.

Comment: @cheng: That's just how a lambda function is defined.

Comment: @TonyK Did you compile the code? int mx = [] () -> struct { int x, y ; } { return { 99, 101 } ; } ().x ; This line can not compile in my environment: g++ 4.4.5 and ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @cheng: I certainly did! Did you compile with `std=c++0x` ?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I compile with -std=c++0x option. I paste my code in my original question. See the edit part for details.

Comment: @cheng: Here is your code, exactly as written, compiling without errors at ideone: http://ideone.com/VsSYk It looks like your version of g++ is too old. What does `g++ --version` produce?

Comment: @TonyK: [It doesn't work with `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1`](https://gist.github.com/1353510)

Comment: @J.F.: OK, thanks for that. It worked with g++ 4.5.2 but they killed it in later versions.

Answer (score 5):

Not they can't. As indicated in the error message, from ISO/IEC 14882:2011 8.3.5/9:

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type (possibly cv-qualified) unless the function definition is nested within the member-specification for that class (including definitions in nested classes defined within the class).

And you can't, of course, name an existing anonymous type as the return type in a function declaration as an anonymous class has no name.

Although you can create a `typedef` for an unnamed class and use that as a return type, as the typedef name becomes the name of the class type for linkage purposes the class isn't really anonymous any more.

Comment: is it still true for C++17?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Test {} * a;
decltype(a) fun() {
  return a;
}
```

btw, `struct Test {}` is not an anonymous struct.

Comment: decltype can not compile in my environment. I use g++ under linux(ubuntu 10.10), gcc version is 4.4.5. I have included <typeinfo> head file.

Comment: @cheng: you don't need a special header. `decltype` is a part of c++11 standard. I've compiled it using gcc that comes with current ubuntu.

Comment: What is your gcc version? I am not sure whether gcc 4.4.5 supports this feature of C++ 11.

Comment: It looks like you can actually remove the name from `Test`.  http://ideone.com/jjWLj

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Thank you for your help. I compile this code with the following: g++ xx.cpp -std=c++0x

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: `struct {int x,y} a;` is also not an anonymous struct due to `a` name. Here's an anonymous struct: [`struct { struct(int x;};} a; a.x=1;`](http://ideone.com/60vTY) -- the nested struct is an anonymous one. Anyway the standard supports only anonymous `union`s.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get to what you want is this, in C++14:

```
auto f() { 
    struct {
        int x, y;
    } ret{10,24};
    return ret;
}
int main() {
  printf("%i", f().x);
}
```

The struct is unnamed (ret is a variable name, not a type name), and is returned.

You can still get it if needed with

```
using my_struct = decltype(f());
my_struct another; another.x++;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do anonymous types like that in C++.

You could however, use `typedef` to assign anonymous types new names.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned x;
    unsigned y;
} TPoint;
```

Comment: But that is useless/unnecessary in C++, and not any easier (arguably slightly harder) than just naming the type.

Answer (score 1):

As @Charles's post pretty much answers the question directly quoting from the spec.

Now, I think why *anonymous* type cannot be the return type of a function, is because suppose `f` returns an anonymous type, then what would one write at the calling site?

```
?????  obj = f();
```

What should be written in place of `?????` in the above code?

Comment: @avakar: That is C++11. Even then `auto` is not a type.

Comment: For example: `cout << f().x ;` (See my answer for working code.)

Comment: @TonyK: That is C++11 which doesn't *modify* anything pertaining to *normal* functions. Also, C++11 lambda (which you've used in your example) is a different animal.

Comment: @cheng: Read the above comment

Comment: @Nawaz: Now you're being disingenuous! You claimed that a function can't return an anonymous type because then it would be unusable, right? I am showing you how it *would* be usable (without using lambdas, or anything from C++11) if it was possible. It's as simple as `f().x`.

Comment: @TonyK: That simply doesn't make sense (or it is simply overkill). If `f().x` is ALL that you can get at the calling site, then why not return `x` instead from the function? Why not make the return-type the type of `x`? Even in C++11, you don't get `x` and `y` both at the calling-site. In your code `return { 99, 101 } ;` is simply equivalent to `return 99;`. If so, then why not make the return type simply `int`?

Comment: @TonyK: From your answer : *You can call the function more than once, to access different members*.  That doesn't answer my question, as the lambda might produce side-effect.

Comment: @Nawaz: OK, see my *new* updated answer. I think it answers all your objections!